# No return value

Tags: php, return

Can't seem to work out why the return is not correct.  It should be `dir_3`, if `echo` it's correct.

The function checks the `existing_dirs` array, if `$new_dir` exists, if it does if appends `_xx` to `$new_dir` if not it should return the `$new_dir`.  But it does not, however if you `echo $new_dir` it's correct `dir_3`.

Spent hours debugging, whats seems like a simple problem!

Thanks

```
function dir_name($new_dir, $count){
    $existing_dirs = array('dir', 'dir_1', 'dir_2');
    if(in_array($new_dir, $existing_dirs)){ 
        $count ++;
        if($count == 1) {
            $new_dir = $new_dir . '_' . $count;
        }
        if($count > 1){
            $dir_parts = explode('_', $new_dir);
            $new_dir = $dir_parts[0] . '_' . $count;
        }
        dir_name($new_dir, $count);
    } else {
        //echo $new_dir;
        return $new_dir;
    }
}

echo dir_name('dir');
```

Comment: only the `else` has a return? did you mean to have `return dir_name($new_dir, $count);` ?

Comment: Thanks Scuzzy!
Never came across this, but it makes sense to have the return there.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you need return sth in `if` case.

```
function dir_name($new_dir, $count){
    $existing_dirs = array('dir', 'dir_1', 'dir_2');
    if(in_array($new_dir, $existing_dirs)){ 
        $count ++;
        if($count == 1) {
            $new_dir = $new_dir . '_' . $count;
        }
        if($count > 1){
            $dir_parts = explode('_', $new_dir);
            $new_dir = $dir_parts[0] . '_' . $count;
        }
        return dir_name($new_dir, $count);
    } else {
        //echo $new_dir;
        return $new_dir;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks pwxcoo, but Scuzzy already answered this, but I can't assign Scuzzy answer as the correct one.  Sorry new to posting on here!